# jQuery Popup to Delete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery popup to delete the record from table.

Here's what I am doing to call my function:

```
echo '<div id="dialog-confirm">'.'<td>' . '<input type="image" src="delete.png" id = "deleteconfirm" style = "height:20px;margin-left :8px;" onclick = "deleterecord('.$row['id'].')">' . '</td>'.'</div>';
```

And here's my function:

```
function deleterecord ( id ) {
    function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").html("Confirm Dialog Box");

    // Define the Dialog and its properties.
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);
            },
                "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

$('#deleteconfirm').click(fnOpenNormalDialog);

function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
        window.location.href = 'delete_ven.php?id=' + id;
    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
} 
}
```

Any help? It's not working.

Comment: This is what I am doing to call my function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callback method doesn't get any information about row ID. For example you could change following lines:

```
callback(true);
```

to

```
callback(id);
```

and

```
window.location.href = 'delete_ven.php?id=' + id;
```

to

```
window.location.href = 'delete_ven.php?id=' + value;
```

Edit: Additionally remove all lines containing "fnOpenNormalDialog" and fix the code accordingly. The click event is assigned in html already, and the function inside function isn't meant work this way.

Comment: In that case will be a problem with id=0, but is easy to solve using a second argument or a different function for "No", he can even put the `alert("Rejected");` in there.